# What is the differece between these XML validation methods?

Tags: .net, xsd, xml-validation

I try to validate XML against XSD. I found several ways to do that. These two works well writing all errors so what is intend use of each?

**XmlDocument and XmlSchema classes**

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(xmlFilePath);    
document.Schemas.Add(@namespace,schemaFilePath);
document.Validate(ValidationHandler);
-----    
public void ValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

**XmlReaderSettings class**

Here I can make some settings and validation happens as early as Load() is executed.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);
settings.Schemas.Add(@namespace, schemaFilePath));
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFilePath, settings);
document.Load(reader);
reader.Close();
-----
public void ValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is between the `XmlReader` and `XmlDocument` classes. `XmlReader` streams the XML and reads it one node at a time. `XmlDocument` on the other hand reads the whole XML into memory and works with that. So, generally, `XmlDocument` is easier to use, but is unsuitable for huge files.

As far as validation is concerned, it seems the classes are comparable, so either choose the one that is easier to use for you (probably `XmlDocument`) or choose `XmlReader` if you expect big files or if low memory consumption is important.

Also, to validate using `XmlReader`, you don't need to use `XmlDocument.Load()` as you do, something like `while (reader.Read()) { }` should be sufficient.